# Double background image on new chapter

Tags: graphics, backgrounds, clearpage

I'm using this [OverLeaf thesis template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-a-masters-slash-doctoral-thesis/mkzrzktcbzfl) and I am trying to put background images on the page that state a new chapter (placed on the right page) but also on the blank left page before it.

I have two images for this and am able to place the right image by placing a Tikz command after the `\chapter` command:

`(\tikz[remember picture,overlay] \node[opacity=0.2,inner sep=0pt] at (current page.center){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{Chapter_background_right.png}};)`

How do I place the image on the left blank page? This empty page is generated automatically by calling the `\chapter` command I believe.

I was able to do it by adding a Tikz command to the `\DeclareDocumentCommand\cleardoublepage{}...` declaration but then it added the image also to appendix headers etc. which I do not want.

Is there a way to place a Tikz image on a previous page for example?

EDIT: For now I removed any automation by `openany` in the document class and manually put the chapter pages and image page in front per chapter. I'll leave this question here but if you only have a few chapters the manual way might be an easier solution.

Comment: What should happen if the page on the left is not empty?

Comment: I am forcing blank pages so that there is always an empty page on the left

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you need?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\title{Sections and Chapters}
\author{Overleaf}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter{An Introduction to Lua\TeX}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-duck}}

qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
\newpage
\Huge{IT IS CLEAR PAGE}
\newpage

\chapter{Lua\TeX: Background and history}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}}
\section{Introduction}
Lua\TeX{} is, in \TeX{} terms, “the new kid on the block” despite having been in active development for over 10 years.


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No but thanks for the effort. It is a book in the end and basically it is a two page image (left A and right B) and the title is on the right page.